# JQuery : $.get() takes too long

Tags: jquery, ajax

In a for loop i have the following code:

```
$.get( "/aQ_OX/LOCAL/ASPXGENERATED/"+array[im], function( data )
{
     var targetTitle = $(data).find('#title').html();
     var targetDate = $(data).find('#date').html(); 
     var targetPdf = $(data).find('#pdf').html(); 

    //some code

});
```

`array` contains some page names. Unfortunately, it takes way too long to load (3 seconds). I'm trying to find a way to increase the speed of this request. Does anyone have advice? Is it possible to load all the page names in a single request?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should make server provide you this information.

Comment: Sounds like your server is taking a longer than expected time to return the data. You should look at the server-side code that is generating that data — is it inefficient, bloated, slow and etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myVar = array.join("-");

$.get( "/aQ_OX/LOCAL/ASPXGENERATED/"+myVar, function( serverData)
{
    dataArray = serverData.split("||"); //|| being some special character
    foreach(data in dataArray){
    //...
    }
});
```

you could process server side by splitting myVar

Comment: hum... my var contains all the pages separated by a "-" .. i don't think the url will work

Comment: you could find appropriate separators that is unique in paramaters